# how can I put Caption with tabular

Tags: captions

[image]I had difficulty doing caption for the following set of images. I have done several codes and I was able to have the caption by doing "subfloat", however, with subfloat it was hard for me to do the vertical and horizontal lables. Someone suggested I use the following code to lable the images vertically and horizontally but the code he gave me was using "tabular' , how can I insert caption in the following code. Also, how can I put the labels on left  at the center of the images.
update: I added a picture in which the figure still needs to be extended vertically to fill a whole page. The code below produces the figure on left (page 48) while another code produced the one on right. Both of them do not extend the figure vertically to get red of the extra space seen on top and at the bottom of the page and thus,both of them did not satisfy my needs yet.

thanks![image]

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\adjustimage{width=.94\textwidth}{phasebar.eps}}\\
        &\begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            w=10nm
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            w=40nm
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=.28\textwidth}
            w=100nm
        \end{adjustbox}\\
        \begin{sideways} t=10nm \end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase10t10w125x300y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase10t40w250x400y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase10t100w340x500y}\\
        \begin{sideways} t=30nm \end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase30t10w200x400y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase30t40w350x750y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase30t100w550x1200y}\\
        \begin{sideways} t=50nm \end{sideways}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase50t10w300x600y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase50t40w600x1100y}&
        \adjustimage{width=.29\textwidth}{phase50t100w600x1500y}\\

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please edit your code to make it compilable. We should be able to cut, paste and hit compile to reproduce what you are seeing. That means you also need to replace images with ones we all have (e.g. from the `mwe` package). Or you can specify their dimensions and pass `graphicx` the `demo` option to replace them with black boxes.

Comment: In your `adjustbox` environments, you should write `10\,nm`, `40\,nm`, and so on. Even better, typeset units with the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align them you need `valign=c` and enclose the entire `tabular` inside `figure` environment.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox,showframe}            %% remove showframe in your document
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
   \centering
    \begin{tabular}{C{0.03\textwidth}*{3}{C{\dimexpr0.31\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}}}
        &\multicolumn{3}{C{\dimexpr0.97\textwidth-4\tabcolsep\relax}}{\adjustimage{width=\linewidth}{phasebar.eps}}\\
        &   $w=\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$
        &   $w=\SI{40}{\nano\meter}$
        &   $w=\SI{100}{\nano\meter}$\\
        \begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90,valign=c}
           $t=\SI{10}{\nano\meter}$
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase10t10w125x300y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase10t40w250x400y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase10t100w340x500y}\\[10mm]
        \begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90,valign=c}
         $t=\SI{30}{\nano\meter}$
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase30t10w200x400y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase30t40w350x750y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase30t100w550x1200y}\\[10mm]
        \begin{adjustbox}{rotate=90,valign=c}
         $t=\SI{50}{\nano\meter}$
        \end{adjustbox}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase50t10w300x600y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase50t40w600x1100y}&
        \adjustimage{width=\linewidth,valign=c}{phase50t100w600x1500y}\\
    \end{tabular}
   \caption{This is my one big figure\label{fig:somefig}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Harish, thanks for the help. Actually, I needed to do a caption for the whole thing( all pictures together). I do not want to name each single picture. I only want to keep the three (w) and three (t) but want to replace the captions a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j with only one caption for the whole thing.

Comment: @Naema Please see the edit. I have also used `siunitx` for the units and adjust `10mm` suitably.

Comment: thanks Harish, that is exactly what i wanted. I am wondering if I can stretch the figure somehow to let it fill a whole page instead of half, what should I change in the code to get the figure stretched vertically?.

Comment: @Naema See the update. You may adjust the dimensions in the argument of `C`

Comment: Harish, the last update you did worked but caused my thesis to be all bounded including this figure . Is there a way to let such a figure fill a whole page without having those boundaries around?

Comment: @Naema: My fault!. Please remove `\usepackage{showframe}`.

Comment: I did it, it removes the boundaries and the figure is alone in the page without any text around but the figure is still the same size! it did not extend vertically to fill a larger area of the page!.

Comment: Harish, I did update my question and added an image, please see it.

Comment: @Naema What is missing? Can you please tell?

Comment: the figure is not extended in size, it is still about half page in length vertically, I prefer if it fills the whole page( it gets bigger and fill the whole page)

Comment: @Naema Well it fills the width. If it fills both, it will get distorted. You may add a `\vfill` before and after the picture to make it vertically centered.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18949/discussion-between-naema-and-harish-kumar).